# Unexpected behavior of lock_guard in C++ 11 multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here's sample which demonstrate the unexpected behavior of `lock_guard`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>


class OddEven
{
private:
        static const int max = 400;
        std::mutex mut;
public:
        OddEven(){}
        OddEven(const OddEven& oddeven)
        {
                //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(oddeven.mut);
        }
        void printEven()
        {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
                for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
                {
                        if (i%2 == 0)
                                std::cout<<i;
                        else
                                std::cout<<" ";
                }
                std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
        void printOdd()
        {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
                for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
                {
                        //std::cout<<(((i%2)!=0)?i:' ');
                        if (i%2 != 0)
                                std::cout<<i;
                        else
                                std::cout<<" ";
                }
                std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        OddEven oddeven;
        std::thread t1(&OddEven::printEven,oddeven);
        std::thread t2(&OddEven::printOdd,oddeven);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        return 0;

}
```

Expected behavior: even numbers than odd or vice versa

Comment: Outside links to code are frowned upon, and it would be helpful to see the actual output you're getting.

Comment: i will remember thanks @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you added a copy constructor to shut the compiler up about being unable to copy `OddEven`. But the compiler was trying to help you.

What happens is that when you create the thread, you give both threads their own `OddEven` object, each with its own mutex. Thus, locking does nothing.

The compiler was probably telling you that it can't copy the `OddEven` when you created the thread, because it couldn't generate the copy constructor, because a mutex is not copyable. But instead of asking why the object was copied there, you instead created a copy constructor that gives the new object its own mutex.

The solution is to remove the copy constructor and wrap the `oddeven` object in the call with `std::ref`, so that a reference to the single object is passed, instead of each thread getting its own object.

As a side note, you should not post your code as an external link, you should post it inline. Much easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your self explanatory explanation, so in total there will be 3 objects 1 in main and 2 are their copies. 

But when i used static variable to count total objects which are created in program it returns 5, why so ?

Comment: @ManojVerma There may be additional temporary copies created somewhere in the thread start machinery.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not with `lock_guard` but with `thread`. `thread` copies/moves the arguments into somewhere that is thread private and accessible to the thread. Since you are providing an lvalue, your `oddeven` object is getting copied, so you end up with two distinct object operating on two distinct `mutex`es.

The compiler would've protected you from this because by default your `oddEven` class is noncopyable and nonmovable due to a member (the `mutex`) being noncopyable and nonmovable. But by writing your own copy constructor you bypass this protection. Don't do this and think about the errors the compiler gives you.

### Ways to do this properly:

Pass the arguments wrapped in a `std::ref` or use a lambda

#### `std::ref`

```
OddEven oddeven;
std::thread t1(&OddEven::printEven, std::ref(oddeven));
std::thread t2(&OddEven::printOdd, std::ref(oddeven));
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

#### lambda

```
OddEven oddeven;
std::thread t1([&oddeven] { oddeven.printEven(); });
std::thread t2([&oddeven] { oddeven.printOdd(); });
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::thread t1(&OddEven::printEven,oddeven);
std::thread t2(&OddEven::printOdd,oddeven);
```

call order unpredictable or even or odd. need to add event for sync:

```
printEven(){
  ...

 ...
 SetEvent(EvenCalculationDoneEvent)
} 
printOdd(){...
 WaitForSingleObject(EvenCalculationDoneEvent);
....
}
```

std::mutex mut -- sync console output only, not a calculation order
simple to check like this:

```
std::thread t1(&OddEven::printEven,oddeven);
Sleep(100);
std::thread t2(&OddEven::printOdd,oddeven);
```